# Firebase giving that db.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the tutorial on the youtube and I have successfully created Firebase project and created Firestore database. I have created a demo collection from which I want to pull the data but after I do so I recieve this error:

> TypeError: db.collection(...).onShapshot is not a function

It's really wierd as I'm following the tutorial and on the tutorial there aren't any issues even tho its returning the issue on my pc. I will share the full code and hopefully someone will be able to help me resolve it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Header, Post } from "./components";
import firebase from "firebase";

import "./App.css";

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXX",
  authDomain: "instagram-clone-2ee86.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://instagram-clone-2ee86.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "instagram-clone-2ee86",
  storageBucket: "instagram-clone-2ee86.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "222065421214",
  appId: "1:222065421214:web:0206210d4eb74d7925c48f",
  measurementId: "G-G37J67K1FW",
});

function App() {
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  // useEffect => Runs a piece of code based on a specific condition
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts").onShapshot((snapshot) => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />

      <div className="app__posts">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <Post
            username={post.username}
            caption={post.caption}
            imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwWdf.png

Any help will mean a lot as I'm stuck on this issue whole day. Thanks! Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "onShapshot", but it should be "onSnapshot".  Check the spelling.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was just too late and I haven't been checking it. Again, thanks so so much!

Answer (score 1):

The real function name is `onSnapshot`

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);
```